# Excel: Finding comma delimited values in reference range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a two-sheet excel file in which I want to see if specific values are present in some column, based on comma separated values in some other cell. The idealized case would be:

Sheet1: Cell A1
"age, name, educational level"

Sheet2: Range A1:A4
{ "age", "car brand", "home adress", "name"}

From this I want a formula that checks if *all* the comma separated values in Sheet1!A1 are existent in the range Sheet2!A1:A4. In the example above, the formula would return something like "Some values not found!" since "educational level" is not existent in the range.

In a scipting environment i would split Sheet1!A1 on "," and then loop over the strings in the array that is produced, but I do not know how to do this in a simple excel formula.

Any clues?

I realize the case is similar to this: [How to reference or vlookup a list of values based on a comma separated list of column references within a cell in excel?](https://superuser.com/questions/439348/how-to-reference-or-vlookup-a-list-of-values-based-on-a-comma-separated-list-of) but i am not skilled enough to understand the answer. :(

Comment: You need this to be a formula instead of a macro?

Comment: Yes, unfortunatley. The document will be collaborated on, so it would raise a lot of questions and be very tiresome to use macro-enabled workbooks.

Comment: There's no way to do this without (a) a Macro or (b) structuring your data differently.